# Any Framework functions helping to find the longest common starting substring of multiple strings?

Tags: c#

I have a list of strings (which represent paths and) which should all have a common beginning (root path). I need to get that common beginning.

That's just a couple of lines to throw together, but I have the nagging feeling that this must be thrown together a million times a year and that there might be an algorithm in the framework that can be used for that, but couldn't find something.
Also, I suppose this has been asked on SO before, but I came up dry.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is interested, here's what I came up with:

```
    public static string GetCommonStartingSubString(IList<string> strings)
    {
        if (strings.Count == 0)
            return "";
        if (strings.Count == 1)
            return strings[0];
        int charIdx = 0;
        while (IsCommonChar(strings, charIdx))
            ++charIdx;
        return strings[0].Substring(0, charIdx);
    }
    private static bool IsCommonChar(IList<string> strings, int charIdx)
    {
        if(strings[0].Length <= charIdx)
            return false;
        for (int strIdx = 1; strIdx < strings.Count; ++strIdx)
            if (strings[strIdx].Length <= charIdx 
             || strings[strIdx][charIdx] != strings[0][charIdx])
                return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: take for example: c:\two and c:\three ...this solution will return c:\t instead of c:\ - so you must trim the output back to the last \.

Answer (score 1):

This method should work:

```
string GetLongestCommonPrefix(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    return items.Aggregate(default(string), GetLongestCommonPrefix);
}

string GetLongestCommonPrefix(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null)
        return s1 ?? s2;

    int n = Math.Min(s1.Length, s2.Length);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            break;
    }
    return s1.Substring(0, i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Excuse my ordinary variable naming, and it's not very fast, but this should do:

```
// your list of strings...
List<string> strings;    

string shortestString = strings.First(x => x.Length == 
    strings.Select(y => y.Length).Min());
while (!strings.All(s => s.StartsWith(shortestString)))
{
    shortestString = shortestString.Substring(0, shortestString.Length - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea to simplify your implementation is to write just a method to get the longest substring of two strings and then use `Aggregate` method from LINQ. Something like:

```
strings.Skip(1).Aggregate(strings.First(), GetCommonSubString);
```

I don't think there is any elegant way to implement `GetCommonSubstring` using standard methods for working with strings. If you care about performance, then you'll probably have to implement it in the "direct" way. A slower, but shorter alternative using LINQ could look something like this:

```
var chars = 
  str1.Zip(str2, (c1, c2) => new { Match = c1 == c2, Char = c1 })
      .TakeWhile(c => c.Match).Select(c => c.Char).ToArray();
return new string(chars);
```

This first "zips" the two strings and then takes parts where the characters are the same using `TakeWhile`. The rest generates an array of characters that can be used to create a string with the result.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Maybe I simplify your problem too much but what about</strike>

`var rootPath = paths.Select(s => new {path = s, depth = s.Split('\\').Length}).
                   Aggregate((memo, curr) => curr.depth < memo.depth ? curr : memo).path;`

Desperate, most probably slow, and all around pretty silly try

```
var paths = new List<string> { @"C:\Ruby19\lib\ruby\gems",
                               @"C:\Ruby19\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.2",
                               @"C:\Ruby19\lib\ruby\gems",
                               @"C:\Ruby19\lib\test\fest\hest"};

var rootPath = paths.Select(s => new { p = s.Split('\\') })
                    .Aggregate((memo, curr) => new { p = curr.p.TakeWhile((stp, ind) => stp == memo.p.ElementAtOrDefault(ind)).ToArray() })
                    .p.Join("\\");
```

=> rootPath = "C:\Ruby19\lib"

Comment: This only works as long as the shortest path is the base path.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (like many others) some time ago. Here is the solution i came up with this. I didn't make any performance measurements but i hadn't any problems with lists of 100 elements.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FEV.TOPexpert.Common.Extensions
{
    public static class IEnumerableOfStringExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the most common left string in a sequence of strings.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The sequence to search in.</param>
        /// <returns>The most common left string in the sequence.</returns>
        public static string MostCommonLeftString(this IEnumerable<string> source)
        {
            return source.MostCommonLeftString(StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Finds the most common left string in a sequence of strings.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">The sequence to search in.</param>
        /// <param name="comparisonType">Type of the comparison.</param>
        /// <returns>The most common left string in the sequence.</returns>
        public static string MostCommonLeftString(this IEnumerable<string> source, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

            string mcs = String.Empty;

            using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                if (!e.MoveNext())
                    return mcs;

                mcs = e.Current;
                while (e.MoveNext())
                    mcs = mcs.MostCommonLeftString(e.Current, comparisonType);
            }
            return mcs;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a sequence with the most common left strings from a sequence of strings.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">A sequence of string to search through.</param>
        /// <returns>A sequence of the most common left strings ordered in descending order.</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<string> MostCommonLeftStrings(this IEnumerable<string> source)
        {
            return MostCommonLeftStrings(source, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a sequence with the most common left strings from a sequence of strings.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="source">A sequence of string to search through.</param>
        /// <param name="comparisonType">Type of comparison.</param>
        /// <returns>A sequence of the most common left strings ordered in descending order.</returns>
        public static IEnumerable<string> MostCommonLeftStrings(this IEnumerable<string> source, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

            var listOfMcs = new List<string>();

            using (var e = source.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (e.Current == null)
                        continue;

                    string removeFromList = String.Empty;
                    string addToList = String.Empty;

                    foreach (var element in listOfMcs)
                    {
                        addToList = e.Current.MostCommonLeftString(element, comparisonType);

                        if (addToList.Length > 0)
                        {
                            removeFromList = element;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (removeFromList.Length <= 0)
                    {
                        listOfMcs.Add(e.Current);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (addToList != removeFromList)
                    {
                        listOfMcs.Remove(removeFromList);
                        listOfMcs.Add(addToList);
                    }
                }
            }

            return listOfMcs.OrderByDescending(item => item.Length);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a string that both strings have in common started from the left.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="first">The first string.</param>
        /// <param name="second">The second string.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a string that both strings have in common started from the left.</returns>
        public static string MostCommonLeftString(this string first, string second)
        {
            return first.MostCommonLeftString(second, StringComparison.InvariantCulture);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a string that both strings have in common started from the left.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="first">The first string.</param>
        /// <param name="second">The second string.</param>
        /// <param name="comparisonType">Type of comparison.</param>
        /// <returns>Returns a string that both strings have in common started from the left.</returns>
        public static string MostCommonLeftString(this string first, string second, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            if (first == null
                || second == null)
                return null;

            int length = Math.Min(first.Length, second.Length);
            first = first.Substring(0, length);
            second = second.Substring(0, length);

            while (!first.Equals(second, comparisonType))
            {
                first = first.Substring(0, first.Length - 1);
                second = second.Substring(0, second.Length - 1);
            }

            return first;
        }

        private static bool MatchesWithList(string match, IList<string> elements, StringComparison comparisonType)
        {
            string removeFromList = String.Empty;
            string addToList = String.Empty;

            foreach (var element in elements)
            {
                addToList = match.MostCommonLeftString(element, comparisonType);

                if (addToList.Length > 0)
                {
                    removeFromList = element;
                }
            }

            if (removeFromList.Length > 0)
            {
                if (addToList != removeFromList)
                {
                    elements.Remove(removeFromList);
                    elements.Add(addToList);
                }
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following returns the longest common prefix of any set of `IEnumerable<T>` not just strings.

```
public static bool Same<T>(this IEnumerable<T> xs) {
  return !xs.Any() || !xs.Skip(!xs.Skip(1).All(x => x.Equals(xs.First()));
}

public static IEnumerable<T> CommonPrefix<T>(this IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> xss) {
  var r = new List<T>();
  var es = xss.Select(x => x.GetEnumerator()).ToList();
  while (es.Select(x => x.MoveNext()).All(x => x))
     if (!es.Select(x => x.Current).Same())
        return r;
     return r;
  }
}
```